# Which menial tasks is Samwell Tarly executing in the Citadel?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, game-of-thrones

I know he is at the Citadel to become a Maester, and of course to study how to kill White Walkers.

But he is cleaning other's shits? Are they pooping in their plate?

[image: sam_washing]

Comment: Good thoughts :)

Comment: Gotta get round to activating Windows, my man.

Comment: `I know he is at the Citadel to become a Grand Maester`, how do you know that? He's there to become a Maester, not **the** Grand Maester. There is a hierarchy. Maester->Arch-Maester->Grand Maester. There are thousands of Maesters, then there are a handful of Arch-Maesters and then there is only one Grand Maester.

Comment: @Aegon Lol, thats not the point. Anyway Edited :)

Comment: He's being Miyagi'd!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Collect library books
   
  [image]
  The maesters make use of books which Sam goes around collecting when they are finished, sparing them the trip to their archival location. Sometimes the maesters will drop their books on the stack he is carrying.
- Place books back in the library, in the correct place
  [image]
  Sam puts these books in a trolley and goes around the library depositing the aforementioned books in their correct place.
- Collect bedpans
  [image]
  A bedpan is a pot used by bedridden patients to urinate or defecate into, so they don't have to make use of a chamber pot (a toilet). Sam collects these into a trolley from under the beds.
- Empty and scrub bedpans
  [image]
  [image]
  Sam (and other trainees) are seen scrubbing the bedpans after emptying them of their contents, using water and a brush.
- Serving food
  [image]
  Sam serves people a brown stew/soup by ladling spoonfuls of it onto their bowls.
  It is no coincidence that it has a similar colour, consistency and even sound effect to the feces in the bedpans, nor that the bowls it is served in is also similar. This is being shown to us in a supercut of cleaning and serving in order to convey how boring, disgusting and menial Sam's routine is.
  [image]
  The bread in this still looks like the turds he is seen emptying in a previous shot.
- Lab assistant
  [image]
  We can see Sam assisting a maester in a biopsy/organ procurement procedure, in which a maester's (Maester Weyland) corpse has been surgically cut open to extract organs for weighing (which Sam has to do). Also, Sam is ordered to clean the place up, suggesting the role of Lab Assistant borrows from his other tasks of servitude.
- Collect food utensils from (and presumably serve food to) isolated/imprisoned patients
  [image]
  Later on in the episode we can see Sam pushing a trolley with which he collects bowls of food from the door windows of patients' chambers. Presumably he also served that food. We don't know yet whether these patients are guests with private chambers, patients with conditions that require isolation/quarantine, or prisoners. One would assume it's a little of both (quarantined and imprisoned patients), judging by Jorah's behaviour, but this is outside the scope of the question.

Answer (score 2):

It was meant to cause you to do a double-take. The bedpans and soup bowls (and the contents of each) appear to be the same, but they're not. The bowls contain brown, unappetizing looking soup; the bedpans contain what bedpans usually contain.